# Why char array to int work reverse in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, binary, char, integer

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned char bytes[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    unsigned int a;
    std::memcpy(&a, bytes, 4);
    std::cout << a << std::endl; // result: 67305985
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to convert char array to int, and I found something weird. The "a" is 67305985, and it can be converted to `00000100000000110000001000000001` in online converter(webpage). And `00000100, 00000011, 00000010, 00000001` is eqaul to `4, 3, 2, 1`'s binary. Why these thing happen and how computer works in these time?

*ps. I wasn't try to convert char array `{1, 2, 3, 4}` to int `1234`. Just did that for curiosity.

Comment: [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: This order of how integer values are represented in memory is called endianness, and depends on the cpu architecture.

Comment: Okay. Now I understant a little about endian. But I have a problem too...

`#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned char bytes[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    unsigned char bytes2[] = {4, 3, 2, 1};
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
    std::memcpy(&a, bytes, 4);
    std::memcpy(&b, bytes2, 4);
    std::cout << a << std::endl; // result: 67306033
    std::cout << b << std::endl; // result: 16909060
    return 0;
}`

I think 'b' should be a 67306033, but it isn't. Why these result happen?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the last answer, your usage is not wrong but the program works on Endianness, largest value in smallest space and smallest value in largest space. Generally `memcpy` is used for copying data from a type to the same type. Your code is interesting since I have not seen many examples like it, keep up the curiosity!

Comment: I just read it now, but I can't find what is wrong usage in my code. Could you tell me that what the problem is?

Comment: What is the end result you want your code to give? Sorry, but I did not understand your question clearly.

Comment: There is nothing result that I want to my code(just learning c++). I only want to know why 'a' is 67305985. And my comment above is question why you said my usage of std::memcpy is wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry for the previous answer, I have edited it and reanswered again, hope its helpful :)